# Traverse struct with reflect, create new slice of pointer type with reflect

Tags: go

Context: I'm trying to take any `struct`, and fill it with random data.

My big sticking point at the moment is that if a `struct` has a field that is a slice with a pointer type (ie. `[]*Foo`), I'm unable to figure out how to create data for that struct using reflection.

Here's what my function currently looks like:

```golang
func randFill(in interface{}) interface{} {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(in)
    v := reflect.ValueOf(in)

    if v.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        v = v.Elem()
    }

    switch v.Kind() {
    case reflect.Struct:
        newStr := reflect.New(t).Elem()
        for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
            newV := randFill(reflect.New(t.Field(i).Type).Interface())
            newStr.Field(i).Set(reflect.ValueOf(newV))
        }

        return newStr.Interface()
    case reflect.Slice:
        num := rand.Intn(10)
        slice := reflect.MakeSlice(v.Type(), num, num)

        for j := 0; j < num; j++ {
            newC := slice.Index(j)
            if newC.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
                ncInt := reflect.New(newC.Type())
                newC = ncInt.Elem()
            }
            gen := randFill(newC.Interface())
            slice.Index(j).Set(reflect.ValueOf(gen))
        }

        return slice.Interface()
    //
    // ... there are other cases down here for handling primitives
    //
    }

    return nil
}
```

This works great on a slice without pointer types, but here's an example of some structs that it has trouble with:

```golang
type Parent struct {
    Name     string
    Age      int
    Children []*Child
}

type Child struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}
```

Where if I created a `Parent{}` and passed it into `randFill(Parent{})`, it has trouble generating values for `*Child` because when it gets to this line:

```golang
newC := slice.Index(j)
```

The value of `newC` at this point, when handling the slice of `[]*Child` is `(*Child)(nil)`, and it's a `reflect.Value` type.

```golang
newC := slice.Index(j)
fmt.Printf("%#v, %T", newC, newC) // Outputs: (*Child)(nil), reflect.Value
```

There's something I'm missing around being able to initialize a pointer type, from a `reflect.Value`, or I've created the incorrect type of slice, and that is the root of my problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you find put that the element is a pointer, you have to create an instance of the type the pointer points to, but you're creating a new pointer. Try this:

```
if newC.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
    ncInt := reflect.New(newC.Type().Elem())
    newC = ncInt.Elem()
}
```

Comment: Tried this just now, and received this error: `panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Type on zero Value`. I think because it's uninitialized, or a nil pointer, it views it as a nil value and panics.

Comment: Fixed the code, try again pls. You already got the first element in the slice, so it is initialized, but nil.

Comment: Yes, this is working, thank you! It's a different panic now (about `Child` not being able to set value for `*Child` type) but that's a different question.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach is to write a function that fills a reflect.Value with random data.  The function calls itself recursively for structured values (slices, structs, ...).

```
func randFillValue(v reflect.Value) {
    switch v.Kind() {
    case reflect.Ptr:
        v.Set(reflect.New(v.Type().Elem()))
        randFillValue(v.Elem())
    case reflect.Struct:
        for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
            randFillValue(v.Field(i))
        }
    case reflect.Slice:
        num := rand.Intn(10)
        v.Set(reflect.MakeSlice(v.Type(), num, num))
        for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
            randFillValue(v.Index(i))
        }
    case reflect.Int:
        v.SetInt(10)  // TODO: fill with random int
    case reflect.String:
        v.SetString("random string") // TODO: fill with random string
    }
    // TODO: add other reflect.Kind
}

// randFill fills the value pointed to pv with random values.
func randFill(pv interface{}) {
    randFillValue(reflect.ValueOf(pv).Elem())
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Wpk-ffBZ9kF).

There are a couple of simplifications in this code compared to the code in the question.  The first is that this answer avoids the `reflect.ValueOf` and `.Interface()` calls by working with `reflect.Value`.  The second is that pointers are handled as a top-level case, thus eliminating the need for pointer related code in the slice element and field code.

Comment: Hey thanks! I'll give this a shot in a bit, but it does look like a much cleaner way of doing what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Awesome, this is working. Had to make a few adjustments, but it looks like I also had to pass in the deref'd `Parent` object at the top. `randFill(&Parent{})`, but that's great, thank you!

Comment: The runnable example on the playground shows the use of a `*Parent` as the argument. I added a comment to this answer to make that requirement clear.